# Search for value contained in array of objects in property of object contained in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, find

can someone help me with this?
I need a function that given a `fieldID`, searchs within `objects` and returns the `objectID` that `fieldID` is in.

```
  const objects = [
    {
      objectID: 11,
      fields: [
        { id: 12, name: 'Source ID' },
        { id: 12, name: 'Source ID' },
      ],
    },
    {objectID: 14,
      fields: [
        { id: 15, name: 'Creator' },
      ],},
    {objectID: 16,
      fields: [
        { id: 17, name: 'Type' },
        { id: 18, name: 'Name' },
        { id: 19, name: 'Description' },
      ],},
  ];
```

SOLVED:
Got it working like this:

```
 const getObjectID = fieldId => {
    for (const object of objects) {
      if (object.fields.find(field => field.id === fieldId)) {
        return object.objectID;
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
const getObjectId = (fieldID) => {
const object = objects.find(object => object.fields.find(field => field.id === fieldID )!== undefined)
if(object) return object.objectID;
return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `find` array method:

```js
const objects = [
  { objectId: 1, fields: ["aaa"] },
  { objectId: 2, fields: ["bbb"] },
  { objectId: 3, fields: ["ccc"] },
];

const getObjectId = (id) => objects.find(object.objectId === id);

console.log(getObjectId(2));
// { objectId: 2, fields: ["bbb"] }
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Thanks, but what I needed to find the value within the array in fields